# Ads Don't fill up the entire screen

Tags: android, admob

Here's my XML File,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="462dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Quotes" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fprev"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/previous"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/previous"
        android:background="@drawable/btn333"
        android:contentDescription="@drawable/radnom"
        android:src="@drawable/eback" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/copy"
        style="@style/ImageButtonpr2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/fprev"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btn222"
        android:contentDescription="@drawable/copy"
        android:src="@drawable/copy" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/quotess" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quotes"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="215dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|top|bottom"
            android:inAnimation="@android:anim/fade_in"
            android:outAnimation="@android:anim/fade_out"
            android:text="@string/h2"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:typeface="monospace" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/previous"
        style="@style/ImageButtonpr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:contentDescription="@drawable/previous"
        android:src="@drawable/previous" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fjprev"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/copy"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/copy"
        android:contentDescription="@drawable/btn4"
        android:src="@drawable/eforward" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/next"
        style="@style/ImageButtonAppTheme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fjprev"
        android:background="@drawable/btn4444"
        android:contentDescription="@drawable/next"
        android:src="@drawable/next" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nm"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/next"
        android:layout_below="@+id/next"
        android:background="#cdcdcd"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="@string/h3"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/highlight"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/h1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />



        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="****"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
        </com.google.ads.AdView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

When I run my app, the first problem is the ads dont show up in Portrait. And when I switch to landscape, the ads don't cover up the topmost region of my app's screen. What can be done? 
I Tried using SMART_BANNER but then I got the error, Not enough space in both orientations.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you haven't specified the location in the relative layout. Try this:

```
 <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="****"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
    </com.google.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: Nope! Whhat I want is to make it cover the entire width of the screen. any idea?

Comment: Yes, I get that. But this makes sure your adView is seen in portrait. As far as matching content of the adview, I don't think that's possible. The banner size is fixed.

Comment: How about a Smart Banner. Anywasy, I've seen apps in which the ads cover the entire width of the screen. even, you might have seen some.

Comment: On xhdpi screens? I've never seen an app which covers the entire screen. On LDPI screens? Yes, I have.